# How to force horizontal orientation?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch, uiviewcontroller

I want to do the following:

ViewControllerA should not go into horizontal orientation
ViewControllerA pushes ViewControllerB 
ViewControllerB should go into horizontal orientation.

Not sure what to set to make this happen.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In each `UIViewController`, you'll need to override the `shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation` method and return a boolean value for each interface orientation you support:

```
// ViewControllerA
-(BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation {
    return (interfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait);
}

// ViewControllerB
- (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation {
    return (interfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait ||
            interfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeLeft ||
            interfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeRight);
}
```

For more information, check out the `UIViewController` [class reference](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/uikit/reference/UIViewController_Class/Reference/Reference.html).

Comment: B won't rotate, because A is portrait since it was pushed by A

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at AlternateViews Apple sample code: it's what you need.

Comment: this won't work if A only supports portrait. B will also only support portrait.

Comment: you don't need to listen for orientation changed as apple sample code does, you only need to present a modal view controller (B) with the desired orientations support. Basically you will have A with a particular orientation support and then if you want to present another view controller with different orientations support just present it as a modal view controller. By doing in this way you are able to swap between different orientations in the apple's way. Hope to be helpful.