# I want my application to start in portrait, but want a second view to start in landscape, how do I do this?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch, orientation

I know the way to get your app to be landscape is to go and make it that way in the info.plist file, but I want my second view to start in landscape. How do i do this?

Comment: What do you mean by second view? Are you using a navigation controller, a tab bar controller or something else?

Answer (score 0):

Create a new view controller for your second view and present it modally.

In your new view controller implement:

```
- (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation
```

to return only the orientations you wish to support.

Answer (score 0):

See also

[How to force horizontal orientation?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3538796/how-to-force-horizontal-orientation/3547591#3547591)