# Force a UIViewController to load a certain orientation

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad, rotation, uiinterfaceorientation

So in my app, I have a navigation stack, where the users can progress through a varity of viewControllers.  Some of the views support multiple orientations, while one of the views does not.  So my question is, how can I force one specific UIViewController to display only in one orientation.  I need this to work both when the view loads for the first time, and when another view is popped off and this view to again visible.  Thanks

I implement this two method to control the rotation of the views:

```
-(void)orientationDidChange:(NSNotification *)notification
-(BOOL)shouldAutoRotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation
```

Thanks

Comment: can you post your implementation of the above delegate methods?

Comment: This question has been asked many times before: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3538796/how-to-force-horizontal-orientation . In short, override the method and change the return value to support only the orientation you want.

Comment: I tried that before I asked - not working

Answer (score 1):

```
    - (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation {
    // Return YES for supported orientations
    return (interfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

**Answer :** `shouldAutoRotateToInterfaceOrientation` method of `UIViewController` Class.

This function returns `YES` if the orientations is supported by your `UIView`. If you `return YES` only to the `landscape orientation`, then the iPhone/iPad will automatically be put in that orientation whenever you load that view.

```
- (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation {
    // Return YES for supported orientations
    return (interfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationLandscape);
}
```